# Generic Method Return Parameter in Java

Tags: java, class, generics

So I've got these 2 Methods:

```
private List<Song> toSongList(String json) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Song> list = null;
        list = mapper.readValue(json, mapper.getTypeFactory()
                .constructCollectionType(List.class, Song.class));
    return list;
}

private List<Interpreter> toInterpreterList(String json) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Interpreter> list = null;
        list = mapper.readValue(json, mapper.getTypeFactory()
                .constructCollectionType(List.class, Interpreter.class));
    return list;
}
```

which I call with:

```
List<Song>songs = toSongList(jsonS);
List<Interpreter>interpreter = toInterpreterList(jsonI);
```

But I want to have a single Method, which I can call like this:

```
List<Song>songs = toList(Song.class, jsonS);
List<Interpreter>interpreter = toList(Interpreter.class, jsonI);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Make your `toList()` method parametrized: `private <T> List<T> toList(Class<T> klass, String json);`

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html for this.

Comment: Btw, `Song.class` instead of `Class.Song`.

Comment: I guess you meant Song.class and Interpreter.class in the last 2 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
private <T> List<T> toList(Class<T> clazz, String json) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<T> list = mapper.readValue(json, mapper.getTypeFactory()
                .constructCollectionType(List.class, clazz));
    return list;
}
```